# WooCommerce Sensei Email customization

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, email-notifications

How can a title or text be changed in one template when the filter is shared across templates?

Plugin code *(in class-woothemes-sensei-email-learner-graded-quiz.php)*:

```
$this->subject = apply_filters( 'sensei_email_subject', sprintf( __( '[%1$s] You have completed a course', 'woothemes-sensei' ), get_bloginfo( 'name' ) ), $this->template);
```

My custom code *(in functions.php)*:

```
add_filter( 'sensei_email_subject', 'my_custom_sensei_email_subject', 'class_woothemes_sensei_email_learner_graded_quiz' );

function my_custom_sensei_email_subject( $subject ) {

    global $woothemes_sensei;

    $subject = sprintf( __( '[%1$s] Your Evaluation has been graded', 'woothemes-sensei' ), get_bloginfo( 'name' ));    

    return $subject;
} 

// This changes the title regardless of which template is being used.
```

Comment: Apologies for the poor syntax

Comment: Thanks, LoicTheAztec!

Comment: Sorry - yes it should have " ); " at the end - but that is in the plugin itself, not my custom code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your function, there is a missing argument, as you can see there is 2 on that filter hook: `$subject` and `$template` (which is optional).

So you will need to add this second argument `$template` in your function. Then in an if statement you can target the correct template only .

Supposing the correct target template slug is: **`learner_graded_quiz`**

So the correct code should be:

```
add_filter( 'sensei_email_subject', 'my_custom_sensei_email_subject', 10, 2 );
function my_custom_sensei_email_subject( $subject, $template ) {
    // Only for your specific template
    if( 'learner-graded-quiz' != $template ) return $subject;

    $subject = sprintf( __( '[%1$s] Your Evaluation has been graded', 'woothemes-sensei' ), get_bloginfo( 'name' ));    

    return $subject;
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.*

Not tested as I don't have sensei…

> You don't need in your code `global $woothemes_sensei;` as it's not used.

Comment: Brilliant - Thank you. I replace your ' ! =' with '==' and thats perfect now!

Comment: OK - many thanks. Are you able to help with another aspect of this? I'm also trying to extract data from an array but with no success yet!